# AVPlayerViewController Does Not Autorotate Video When ShowsPlaybackControls is False

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

Setting the **ShowsPlaybackControls** property on the AVPlayerViewController to false causes the video to no longer rotate with the device orientation. I want it to behave the same way as when it is true which flips the video to match the device orientation. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I've decided if this is the way the native video player for iOS works, then that is the default behavior. Plus it makes sense if you're using it as a background view for a page and would want the orientation to be preserved.